# Limitation of Keras/Tensorflow for solving Linear Regression tasks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression

I was trying to implement linear regression in Keras/TensorFlow and was very surprised how difficult it is. The standard examples work great on random data. However, if we change the input data a little bit, all examples stop work correctly.

I try to find coefficients for `y = 0.5 * x1 + 0.5 * x2`.

```py
np.random.seed(1443)
n = 100000
x = np.zeros((n, 2))
y = np.zeros((n, 1))

x[:,0] =  sorted(preprocessing.scale( np.random.poisson(1000000, (n)) ))
x[:,1] =  sorted(preprocessing.scale( np.random.poisson(1000000, (n)) ) )
y = (x[:,0] + x[:,1]) /2

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add( keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape =(2,), dtype="float32" ))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')

model.fit(x,y, epochs=1000, batch_size=64)
print(model.get_weights())
```

The results:

```
| epochs| batch_size |  bias      | x1         | x2
| ------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
| 1000  | 64         | -5.83E-05  | 0.90410435 | 0.09594361
| 1000  | 1024       | -5.71E-06  | 0.98739249 | 0.01258729
| 1000  | 10000      | -3.07E-07  | -0.2441376 | 1.2441349
```

My first thought was that it is a bug in Keras. So, I tried R/Tensorflow library:

```r
floatType <- "float32"
p <- 2L
X <- tf$placeholder(floatType, shape = shape(NULL, p), name = "x-data")
Y <- tf$placeholder(floatType, name = "y-data")
W <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(list(p, 1L), dtype=floatType))
b <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(list(1L), dtype=floatType))
Y_hat <- tf$add(tf$matmul(X, W), b)
cost <- tf$reduce_mean(tf$square(Y_hat - Y))
generator <- tf$train$GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
optimizer <- generator$minimize(cost)

session <- tf$Session()
session$run(tf$global_variables_initializer())

set.seed(1443)
n <- 10^5
x <- matrix( replicate(p, sort(scale((rpois(n, 10^6))))) , nrow = n )
y <- matrix((x[,1]+x[,2])/2)

i <- 1
batch_size <- 10000
epoch_number  <- 1000
iterationNumber <- n*epoch_number / batch_size

while (iterationNumber > 0) {
  feed_dict <- dict(X = x[i:(i+batch_size-1),, drop = F], Y = y[i:(i+batch_size-1),, drop = F])
  session$run(optimizer, feed_dict = feed_dict)

  i <- i+batch_size
  if( i > n-batch_size)
    i <- i %% batch_size 

  iterationNumber <- iterationNumber - 1
}
r_model <- lm(y ~ x)
tf_coef <- c(session$run(b), session$run(W))
r_coef  <- r_model$coefficients
print(rbind(tf_coef, r_coef))
```

The results:

```
| epochs| batch_size |  bias      | x1         | x2
| ------+------------+------------+------------+-----------
|2000   | 64         | -1.33E-06  | 0.500307   | 0.4996932
|1000   | 1000       | 2.79E-08   | 0.5000809  | 0.499919
|1000   | 10000      | -4.33E-07  | 0.5004921  | 0.499507
|1000   | 100000     | 2.96E-18   | 0.5        | 0.5
```

Tensorflow finds the correct result only when batch size = samples number and the optimization algorithm is SGD. If optimization algorithm was "adam" or "adagrad", errors were much larger.

1. For obvious reasons, I cannot choose hyperparameter `batch_size = n`. Could you recommend any approaches to solve this problem with precision 1E-07 for Keras or TensorFlow?
2. Why TensorFlow finds better solutions than Keras?

***Comment 1.*** 
Based on post "today" below:
Train dataset shuffling will significantly improve the performance of TensorFlow version:

```
shuffledIndex<-sample(1:(nrow(x)))
x <- x[shuffledIndex,]
y <- y[shuffledIndex,,drop=FALSE]
```

For batch size = 2000:

```
|(Intercept)     |       x1  |        x2
|----------------+-----------+----------
|-1.130693e-09   | 0.5000004 | 0.4999989
```

Comment: I liked this question :)

Comment: It resolves my issue in Tensorflow, however, simple keras model was not improved by shuffling train data. This model is so simple that I start to think about a bug in keras library.

Comment: My answer was all in Keras! The issue is not about shuffling or not. It is about sorting! You should not sort the values.

Comment: I am sorry that did not explain well enough. I found this problem when tried to implement simple Moving Average on EUR/USD rates. I can`t attach 100Mb input data here, so I find the closest model - sorted Poisson distribution. Example of real data is : [[1.13005/1.13007], [1.13006/1.13007], [1.13016/1.13018], [1.13026/1.13027]] The real data has similar properties as sorted Poisson. So, I am looking for a solution for sorted data. And it works in TensorFlow, but not in Keras.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, that's because of weight initialization. In your TF code you are explicitly initialize the weight to zero: `tf$zeros(list(p, 1L)`. Do the same in the Keras model by passing `kernel_initializer='zero'` argument to `Dense` layer and you would see that the Keras model would converge to `[0.5, 0.5]` just after two epochs probably with any batch size you set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are sorting the generated random numbers for each feature value. So they end up very close to each other:

```py
>>> np.mean(np.abs(x[:,0]-x[:,1]))
0.004125721684553685
```

As a result we would have:

```py
y = (x1 + x2) / 2
 ~= (x1 + x1) / 2
  = x1
  = 0.5 * x1 + 0.5 * x1
  = 0.3 * x1 + 0.7 * x1
  = -0.3 * x1 + 1.3 * x1
  = 10.1 * x1 - 9.1 * x1
  = thousands of other possible combinations
```

In this case the solution that Keras would converge to would really depend on the initial value of the weights and bias of Dense layer. With different initial values you would get different results (and possibly for some of them, it may not converge at all):

```py
# set the initial weight of Dense layer
model.layers[0].set_weights([np.array([[0], [1]]), np.array([0])])

# fit the model ...

# the final weights
model.get_weights()

[array([[0.00203656],
        [0.9981099 ]], dtype=float32),
 array([4.5520876e-05], dtype=float32)]    # because: y = 0 * x1 + 1 * x1 = x1 ~= (x1 + x2) / 2

# again set the weights to something different
model.layers[0].set_weights([np.array([[0], [0]]), np.array([1])])

# fit the model...

# the final weights
model.get_weights()

[array([[0.49986306],
       [0.50013727]], dtype=float32),
 array([1.4176634e-08], dtype=float32)]    # the one you were looking for!
```

However, if you don't sort the features (i.e. just remove `sorted`) it is very likely that the converged weights to be very close to `[0.5, 0.5]`.

Comment: Actually, I tried to simulate financial price. Sorted numbers from Poisson distribution is the simplest model. Your detailed explanation helps me to understand the partial solution for TensorFlow version.
If we shuffle our train data, TensorFlow will converge with much smaller batch size ~2000 samples. 
Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. Great solution and explanation.